# Exception when load table containing data from sqlite3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, exception

I'm developing iPhone app , I created a view controller that contains a button and tableViewController that must show the data form sqlite3 , I'm using xcode 3.4 
I want the button that in viewController open the TableViewController , when I try to open that table itself without button I go to the storyboard and put the raw on the TableViewController and it loads the data of sqlite normally 
but when I put the raw on the viewController and connect the button to the TableViewController and make the connection modal then run .. when I press the button, it gives me the following Exception: 
`NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`

and the exception refers to a line in (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`)

here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

Books *temp= (Books *)[self.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


// [cell setText:temp.bo_name];
[cell setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %@ - %d - %d - %d - %d - %@ - %f - %f - %@ - %f - %d - %@ - %d",temp.bo_id, temp.bo_name, temp.bo_au_id, temp.bo_pub_id, temp.bo_num_pages, temp.bo_publish_year, temp.bo_about, temp.bo_price, temp.bo_currency, temp.bo_cover_img, temp.bo_recomended, temp.bo_sec_id, temp.bo_path, temp.bo_sort]];

return cell;

}
```

**Edit** to add the types of the instance variables specified in the comment on my answer - JeremyP.

```
int bo_id; 
NSString *bo_name; 
int bo_au_id; 
int bo_pub_id; 
int bo_num_pages; 
int bo_publish_year; 
NSString *bo_about; 
double bo_price; 
double bo_currency; 
NSString *bo_cover_img; 
double bo_recomended; 
int bo_sec_id; 
NSString *bo_path; 
int bo_sort;
```

Comment: what line exactly does it refer to?

Comment: this line:[cell setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %@ - %d - %d - %d - %d - %@ - %f - %f - %@ - %f - %d - %@ - %d",temp.bo_id, temp.bo_name, temp.bo_au_id, temp.bo_pub_id, temp.bo_num_pages, temp.bo_publish_year, temp.bo_about, temp.bo_price, temp.bo_currency, temp.bo_cover_img, temp.bo_recomended, temp.bo_sec_id, temp.bo_path, temp.bo_sort]];

Answer (score 1):

`setText` is deprecated. Instead of `[cell setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d...`, try

```
cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d...
```

The error might be somewhere in the length of `%d - %@ - %d - %d - %d - %d - %@ - %f - %f - %@ - %f - %d - %@ - %d` causing an argument mismatch (`NSInvalidArgumentException`). Carefully walk through the list to find out the error. It's difficult to tell without seeing what are the data types of the individual elements.

Comment: I did this , but it gives me a lldb with Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1, address= 0x53736902)

Comment: Your mapping is correct! So the problem might be that the object `self.books` is released somewhere before setting the text (Which might be why you get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in your comment above).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say with certainty what the problem is but it's almost certainly that you have a mismatch between an argument in your `stringWithFormat:` and its format specifier.

Check things like all the things corresponding to `%d` are actually ints and not long ints or short ints.  Check that the things that are specified as %@ really are object pointers.  Also, if you have overridden `-description` fore any of the classes used here, make sure you have made no mistakes there.

The actual error is caused by sending `-isEqualToString:` to an `NSIndexSet` so you are probably treating an `NSIndexSet` as a string somewhere by accident.

Comment: I can't understand what I should do exactly :( this is my application , please download it and check it then tell me what is the problem .. really I need a help  .. http://www.mediafire.com/?ho5clejfwws3hue

Comment: @user1338832 Sorry but I don't have time to fix bugs in other people's applications.  Try posting the interface for `Books` in your question as a starter.

Comment: The interface in the application, I can't post it here

Comment: @user1338832 You don't have to post the entire interface, just the types of the ones mentioned, like `bo_id`, `bo_name`, etc

Comment: int bo_id;
    NSString *bo_name;
    int bo_au_id;
    int bo_pub_id;
    int bo_num_pages;
    int bo_publish_year;
    NSString *bo_about;
    double bo_price;
    double bo_currency;
    NSString *bo_cover_img;
    double bo_recomended;
    int bo_sec_id;
    NSString *bo_path;
    int bo_sort;

Comment: I still didn't reached to a solution to my problem

Comment: @Eman87:  Well there's not enough information in your question to answer it.  Try putting the stack trace in.

Comment: @Eman87: What was the issue?  Please write an answer describing how you fixed the problem and then accept it.

Comment: I discovered that I was creating variables with the same name like bo_id and I was importing them in my class and this caused a confliction.. when I changed the names, all fixed

Comment: @Eman87:  you mean it just went away?  Oh, well, it happens sometimes, usually something wasn't compiled that should have been.